# Sqoop: replace charatcters when importing from MySQL to Hive?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

When importing data from MySQL to Hive I need to drop two characters `+7` in phone number. The following request returns SQL error. What is the correct `replace` command should I use?

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://server/db --username xxxx --password yyyy --query 'select name, last_name, email, second_name, Replace(personal_phone, '+7', ''), Replace(mobile, '+7', ''), Replace(phone, '+7', '') from user where $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /data/test -m 1  --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table user_inf`

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://server/db --username xxxx --password yyyy --query "select name, last_name, email, second_name, Replace(phone, "+7", '') as phone, Replace(mobile, "+7", '') as mobile from test where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /data/test -m 1  --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table info`

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` command looks correct. The error might be because of the quotes since you have used single quotes in the beginning. I have changed it to Double quotes in the SQL query. It should work now:

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://server/db --username xxxx --password yyyy --query "select name, last_name, email, second_name, Replace(personal_phone, '+7', ''), Replace(mobile, '+7', ''), Replace(phone, '+7', '') from user where $CONDITIONS" --target-dir /data/test -m 1  --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-import --hive-table user_inf`

Comment: Yes, double quotes helped as well as adding backward slash in `\$CONDITIONS` **Notwithstanding I get exception `FAILED: ParseException line 1:190 cannot recognize input near ''+7'' ',' '''' in column specification`

Comment: Edited my answer again. Please try this. I can not verify this command in my environment so cant guarantee. :)

Comment: Thanks, you need to add 'as' close for this to work (see my answer)

Comment: Great you figured out. :)